# How can I force Ditto to paste the selected clipboard item to the currently active window?

Tags: windows, window, paste, ditto

How can I force Ditto to paste the selected clipboard item to the currently active window?

For example, I select the clipboard #8 (`cadium`):

[image]

I would like it to be pasted to the currently active window. However, from time to time, Ditto pastes it to some other window, in which case the window steals the focus and receives the pasted item. It seems to depends on in which window I copied clipboard #8 (`cadium`).

I use Ditto version 03.22.20.00 64-bit on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. I didn't have this issue when using older (version 03.21.50.00 64-bit) versions of Ditto.

Comment: Either downgrade the version, or change to another product (perhaps [ClipAngel](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clip-angel/)).

Comment: @harrymc thanks, I was wondering whether Ditto version 03.22.20.00 64-bit, which is the most recent stable release, has some kind of setting or know issue regarding on which window the selected clipboard is pasted to.